# Can I connect two PWM DC motor controllers in series to achieve coarse and fine tuning?

Tags: pwm, tuning

Can I connect two PWM DC motor controllers in series to achieve coarse and fine tuning? I would set the (2nd) fine tuning controller to midrange and then adjust the (1st) coarse one first.

Alternatively, is there a pot + two resistors circuit I can add to the PWM DC motor controller potentiometer to give coarse and fine adjustment?

I’m actually trying to achieve finer temperature control of this hot wire cutter.

[image: I’m actually trying to achieve finer temperature control of this hot wire cutter.]

Comment: No, you cannot.

Comment: Two controllers in series? highly doubt it. But you could add two potentiometers in series instead of one potentiometer - depending on how it is wired

Comment: You can use a high power rheostat in series with your motor controller though. Or a variable wirewound resistor. But those take a screwdriver to unscrew and adjust the clamp, but they will handle the power.

Comment: Why not just adjust the power supply output?

Comment: (With a compound wound motor, you could have one controller for the field coil and one for the armature - in parallel. Don't drive either to look like that wire, and with a high armature current, be careful when reducing field.)

Comment: (I can almost see two "parallel PWM flyback inductors" feeding the same capacitor.) *Why* mention *motor* controllers?

Comment: _"Alternatively, is there a pot + two resistors circuit I can add to the PWM DC motor controller potentiometer to give coarse and fine adjustment?"_ - Possibly. Exactly which PWM controller do you have?

Comment: Do you intend to use it with the power supply shown, or some other power source?

Comment: Get a voltage controlled power supply

Comment: You know, your power supply already has fine and course knobs on it. What does the motor controller add, that your power supply can't already do? PWM, but why do you need PWM? You can control the hot-wire power by adjusting the power supply voltage.

Comment: For use of parallel PWM, see [EDN on Faster PWM-based DAC](https://www.edn.com/a-faster-pwm-based-dac/), too. The trouble with inductors instead of resistors is current; the remedy I see is to separate *in* from *out*: fly-back.

Comment: The hot wire cutter has a resistance of about .7 ohms. I need the PWM controller between the cutter and the power supply, otherwise the power supply barely drives the wire to a dull orange. Something about impedance matching I think.

Comment: Because your hot wire is so low resistance, the change in power (heat) is changing with the square of the voltage. You need to be CURRENT controlling the wire. Not Voltage controlling it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need it. The power supply in your picture has fine and coarse voltage controls. You can use those (or the fine and course current controls, if you like) to adjust the hot wire's power.

I don't see any reason to use the separate PWM controller, as it doesn't add any extra features, like a thermostat.

Comment: The hot wire cutter has a resistance of about .7 ohms. I need the PWM controller between the cutter and the power supply, otherwise the power supply barely drives the wire to a dull orange. Something about impedance matching I think.

I will try adjusting the power supply current or voltage. The problem with everything turned up all the way, 30 V/10 A, is that the PWM pot becomes very sensitive. It goes from not enough heat in the wire to looking like a lightbulb in a very tiny movement of the dial.

Comment: @LRHann what if you leave the PWM dial alone but change the power supply current or voltage? I bet the PWM controller has a capacitor that's smoothing out the current/voltage so the power supply doesn't go into constant current mode - this isn't really the design purpose of the controller so you're probably in uncharted territory seeing much it heats the wire